# jQuery .ajax POST returns null

Tags: php, json, ajax, post

I am trying to post some data to my server and get some data back. For some reason, the data I am posting comes back as **null**:

The jQuery:

```
var data = { message1: "bla", message2: "blabla" };

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://example.com/api',
    data: JSON.stringify(data), // EDIT: replacing this with [data: data,] also does not help (also not in combination with omitting the following line)
    contentType: 'application/json', // EDIT: I have removed this line now, but the problem persists
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
```

The PHP:

```
$response['message1'] = $_POST['message1'];
$response['message2'] = $_POST['message2'];
$response['message3'] = 'blablabla';

print_r(json_encode($response));
```

This returns:

> { message: **null**, message2: **null**, message3: "blablabla" }

And I want:

> { message: **"bla"**, message2: **"blabla"**, message3: "blablabla" }

I have already tried all sorts of combinations of quotes in my data (e.g. `'{"message1": "bla" (...)}'` and omitting the `JSON.stringify`), but nothing seems to work..

Comment: Change `print_r` to `echo` for json return.

Comment: You are passing an array. Convert the array to a string of JSON.

Comment: Actually since you are passing as json, using $_POST vars won't have anything in them. So eliminate `contentType: 'application/json',` and then  change `data: JSON.stringify(data),` to just `data: data,`

Comment: Need to see `$_POST['message1']` suggests its not set.

Comment: PHP fills `$_POST` with data only for `multipart/form-data` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` not 'application/json'

Comment: ^ try removing contentType. Read the paragraph on `contentType` here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#contentType

Comment: Unfortunately, none of this works. I have removed `contentType` now, but it's still the same

Comment: removing the content type doesn't change the data from json, IncredibleHat suggestion of removing the JSON.stringify is also necessary

Comment: I have done that now, but the result is still `null`.. :/

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: `{ message: "bla", message2: "blabla", message3: "blablabla" }` as the question says :)

Comment: Are you sure your API works? Have you checked it through postman or curl?

Comment: I'm taking a shot in the dark here. the problem is with your encoding. Since you said bla bla bla instead of yada yada yada i'm assuming that you came from a latin country (maibe brasil?).

So you're problably sending the data with pontuaction like áóéíú and so on .... or you're returning with those same pontuaction. So, if your page encoding isn't utf-8 you should convert those values before sending that, with $ret['message3'] = utf8_encode("bla bla bla");

Comment: @zuif my API is literally just the PHP code from my question. I guess there isn't much there that could be broken..

Comment: @SamuelAialaFerreira That was one of my first ideas (although I'm from Germany and I exclusively use UTF-8 in my text editor..). But `utf8_encode($_POST['message1'])` returns `message1: ""`

Comment: Still, make sure to verify it from postman, if it works there as expected (that is, returns blabla message), that will confirm that there is something with your ajax call.

Comment: If I use `curl -X POST https://example.com/api/ \
-d '{"message1": "bla", "message2": "blabla"}'`, I get the same as through the AJAX request

Comment: Add the header `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Comment: Same result.. `{"message1":null,"message2":null,"message3":"blablabla"}` So the issue is in my PHP code? But what could be wrong with those 4 lines??? :D

Comment: Jesus... I found the solution! replace `https://example.com/api` with `https://example.com/api/`. Your steps about removing `JSON.stringify` and `contentType` were still necessary though. Thanks!

Comment: Next time, save all that trouble, and always test your API endpoints with Postman